# Font render safari 6

Tags: fonts, macos

i'm using DINNextLTPro-Medium font on [this site](http://kevinchevallier.com/mandrake/) and noticed quite a difference on the rendering between Safari 6 & Chrome (mac) and the rest of the world (Safari 5 mac/win, Chrome win, Firefox win, Opera win...).

Here's what happens on a mac with Safari 6:

[image]

And on Safari 5 win:

[image]

Here's the font call in my css file:

```
@import url("//hello.myfonts.net/count/259bc7");
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DINNextLTPro-Medium';
    src:    url('fonts/259BC7_0_0.eot');
    src:    url('fonts/259BC7_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('fonts/259BC7_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
            url('fonts/259BC7_0_0.ttf') format('truetype')
}

body,input,button,textarea  {
    font-family: DINNextLTPro-Medium, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; border:none;
    font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal; }
```

It all comes from myfonts and it's pretty similar to the fontsquirrel declaration i'm used to, which is know for working very well.

Question is, has anyone got a clue about that? I know that it's hard to get the same render over different browsers, but here, it looks really bold.

EDIT #1: Would it be caused by the videos being loaded from Vimeo (flash) to cause this?

Comment: What font smoothing settings are you using in the Windows version of Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems i've found a fix via css after many searches:

`html {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased}`

Answer (score 0):

Your @font-face looks good and can't see any reason why it wouldn't display in Version 5. However Googling custom fonts Safari 5 its quickly noticeable that lots of people are having rendering issues on this version of Safari.

Strangely enough a lot of people have reported this issue is caused by Adobe Flash and one way of duplicating to see if this is the problem is does the font render quickly before the page loads? As people are reporting its only after the page has completely loaded that it occurs so quick refreshes on the page should be able to replicate to see if this is the problem.

Checkout: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2458648?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Actually it only happens on safari 6, 5 is fine. And yes i didn't write it but i was thinking of flash as one possible source of the problem as i load several iframes from vimeo to display videos.

Comment: I'm not to familiar with safari but I assume it has some kind of firebug? I'll take a look in a couple of hours for ya, are you 100% sure its executing the font correctly and not using a fallback font?

Comment: Yes it's the Din font itself being loaded ok. The fallback is Helvetica and there's a clear difference between both. My problem is that i aint got a mac with safari 6 with me (just my client). Already gave a look on his laptop with the property inspector and all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I use Safari 6 + iMac & IE 10 + Windows 7, this is mainly caused by the different font-rendering techniques used in Mac and Windows.
I ain't sure if you had ever used Mac before or ever noticed the different font-rendering between Mac and Windows.
The character in Mac appears smoother and a bit blur, while in Windows they looks sharp.

Beyond that, you may try adjust ClearType in Windows (Control Panel/Appearance and Personalization/Display/Adjust ClearType text) and font smoothing in Mac (Settings/General).
You may also use Terminal to adjust how heavily fonts are rendered.

```
defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 2
```

-int 1 is lighter than - int 2

For more info on the DIFFERENCE, read this [~article~](http://damieng.com/blog/2007/06/13/font-rendering-philosophies-of-windows-and-mac-os-x)