# Font rendering and margin in safari 5 - 6 and chrome

Tags: html, css, safari, text-rendering

I have built an intro animation using jquery.  This looks fine on my machine in all browsers (ff, chrome and safari).

On the clients however, it does not!

Clients screen shot:
http://madmantis.co.uk/debug/screen-shot-client.png

My screen shot:
http://madmantis.co.uk/debug/screen-shot-vs.png

I just cant figure out what is going on here....perhaps something to do with line wrapping in css?

I am on safari 6, he is on safari 5.  He reports the same problem in chrome, again I dont see the error.

The website is available at http://dev.system2.co.uk

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there has been some changes in the default font rendering method in Safari 6. Here's a little CSS that might work for you:

```
html {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased}
```

Taken from this topic: [Font render safari 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016032/font-render-safari-6)

Comment: nice try but no juice....

I will rewrite the html to have div's for each line with overflow hidden to mask overflow.